# MVC custom roles based off of windows authenticated credentials

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a MVC 5 web applications authenticating users via Windows Authentication. My goal is to implement custom roles based on their windows Authenticatied username. I have seen atricles that explain this, but they build their application on the desgin of user roles, not windows autnetication.

My issues is, how can i add custom roles based off the windows authenticated account?

Comment: Have you tried using a DirectorySearcher object to query for the groups of the user?

Comment: @wertzui - I have not tried using DirectorySeearcher object, but it sounds like that's not what i'm looking for. I want to create my own custom roles/groups that wouldn't be found anywhere else.The roles/groups would be located in my own database

Answer (score 0):

One approach id to add custom filters to the restricted controllers in order to validate access:

```
[HasPermission(EnumSecuredFunctionality.ACCOUNTS)]
public class Account : Controller
{

}
```

Inside your custom filter you can handle your permissions:

```
public class HasPermission : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public EnumSecuredFunctionality[] Actions { get; set; }

    public HasPermission(params EnumSecuredFunctionality[] actions)  //For example you can pass secured functionalities to restrict
    {
        Actions = actions;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        BaseController controller = (BaseController)filterContext.Controller;

        UserAuthData userAuthData = (UserAuthData)controller.ViewBag.UserAuthData;

        if (!controller.UserIsAuthenticated || !controller.ValidatePermission(userAuthData.ShopSeller.LoginName.ToString(), Actions[0]))
        {
            //REDIRECT
            RouteValueDictionary redirectTargetDictionary = new RouteValueDictionary();
            redirectTargetDictionary.Add("action", "ShowMessage");
            redirectTargetDictionary.Add("controller", "Error");
            redirectTargetDictionary.Add("message", "Role " + EnumToString.EnumRoleToString(userAuthData.ShopSeller.EnumRole) + " No permissions");

            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(redirectTargetDictionary);
        }
    }
}
```